# Is it possible to specify property name on projection class in Spring data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

So I have following projection class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CommentDTO3 {

    private Long id;

    private String comment;

    private Long userId;

    private Long placeId;

    private String userUserProfileFirstName;
}
```

This works just fine, however I would like to have `userUserProfileFirstName` property named as `comentator_name`. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
@Value("user.userProfile.firstName")
private String userUserProfileFirstName;
```

I have tested that particular example, but @Value annotation seems to be neglected. 
I am not interested in using `@Query` annotation to provide custom constructor.

**Edit:**

This is what works for me:

```
@JsonProperty("userName")
private String userUserProfileFirstName;
```

This one works not

```
@JsonProperty("userName")
@Value("#{target.user.userProfile.firstName}")
private String userName;
```

and it fails on startup with :

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type User! Traversed path: Comment.user.
```

https://gist.github.com/Antoniossss/7ab00c180013f707ef9a8cdc2d53e807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an experience in using [class-based projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos) with `@Value`, but with 'interface' [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) we can use `@Value` to provide some computation:

```
public interface CommentProjection {

    Long getId();

    String getComment();

    @Value("#{target.user.id}")    
    Long getUserId();

    @Value("#{target.place.id}")              
    Long getPlaceId();

    @Value("#{target.user.userProfile.firstName}")
    String getComentatorName();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've checked a class-based projections - they doesn't work with `@Value`. The trying to use a DTO property name that differs from the Entity property name leads to throwing an exception `PropertyReferenceException: No property <property> found for type <Entity>!` and prevents the Spring context from running.

```
@Data
public class CommentProjection {

    @Value("#{target.user}")    
    private final User theUser; // throw PropertyReferenceException: No property theUser found for type Comment!
}
```

My [demo project](https://github.com/Cepr0/sd-jpa-projections).

**UPDATE**

I've posted a bug report: [DATAJPA-1186](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1186)

**UPDATE**

It's not a bug, it's a [feature](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1186?focusedCommentId=154290&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-154290).

Comment: It looks like @Value just dont work with classes. Fortunetly I can make my DTO an interface as I wont be rather making new instances by myself.

Comment: It should work with classes just as with interfaces. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos So if it doesn't work someone should create a small example and submit a bug. But note that the syntax of the SpEL expression in the question was wrong.

Comment: @JensSchauder I've checked a class-based projections - they also work with @Value annotation. But another issue has been occurred - with dynamic projections - when I'm invoking `<T> Optional<T> findByUserName(String name, Class<T> type)` repo method then  NoSuchElementException is throwing. See my demo [repo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sd-jpa-projections/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/projections/repo/CommentRepo.java) and [tests](https://github.com/Cepr0/sd-jpa-projections/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/cepr0/projections/ProjectionTests.java)..

Comment: @Cepr0 can you try the projection without implementing interface? This would duplicate my approach. In my case app wont start with exception of non existing Comentator property (if i remeber correctly)

Comment: @Antoniossss I tried it without implementing the interface - all worked fine.

Comment: @Cepr0 that is curious. Does not work for me - it neglects Value annotation. If I put ther incxorrect expression - no error occurs. If i put dummy field name - exception hits

Comment: @Antoniossss check if your DTO has c-tor with all args... pay attention to my example - it has 'final' fields that causes `@Data` to create a constructor for all of them.

Comment: @Cepr0 `@AllArgsCostructor` does that as well

Comment: @Cepr0 Adding final modifier didnt change anything. https://gist.github.com/Antoniossss/7ab00c180013f707ef9a8cdc2d53e807

Comment: @Antoniossss you are right! `@Value` doesn't work with class-based projections. (I was mistaken - didn't include a field with a different name to DTO c-tor). See updated answer...

Comment: @JensSchauder I was mistaken - `Value` doesn't work with class-based projection. I've posted a bug report: [DATAJPA-1186](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1186)

Comment: Uhh at least its a bug probably, no need to search for solution anymore. Thanks for the effort!.

Answer (score 0):

Interface-based, both @Value and @JsonProperty worked out of the box in my case, e.g. this one

```
@Projection(types = { Project.class }, name = "website")
public interface ProjectWebAPIProjection {
  Long getId();

  @JsonProperty("geo-x")
  @Value("#{target.objekt?.xKoordinate}")
  Double getGeoX();

// ...
}
```

Comment: And the issue is about class based projections.